Test data for AES based F8 encryption, F9 authentication
I am working on implementation of F8 confidentiality scheme for encryption/decryption and F9 based authentication scheme. These are specified by 3GPP standard, but the implementation in standard is based on Kasumi cipher block.
Unfortunately, in my device, only AES is supported and I have to implement using AES. The implementation seems straightforward, but I can't find any test vector to check it.
Does anyone has test vector for similar implementation?
Lacking a test vector, is it possible to use the Kasumi based test vector instead? I think it's not possible as underlying cipher block is different, so both will generate different results for same input.
